# The 0 field is required. Laravel 5.5 Validation error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Am having a "The 0 field is required." error while trying save data into database when I have no field called 0. without validation from the Controller, the data saves but if I validate even just one field out of the six field I want to validate, I still get the error. How do I solve the issue. Please help out here is my view

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('agent/add_tenantProperty') }}" data-toggle="validator">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtMovieTitle">Tenant</label>
                     <select id="ddlGenge" class="form-control" name="tenant_id" required="">
                       @foreach($tenants as $tenant)
                        <option value="{{ $tenant->id }}">
                          {{ $tenant->designation }} {{ $tenant->firstname }} {{ $tenant->lastname }}
                        </option>
                       @endforeach
                      </select>
                       <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="ddlGenge">Asset Category</label>
                      <select id="ddlGenge" class="form-control" name="asset_id" required="">
                        <option>Choose a Property</option>
                        @foreach($assets as $asset)
                         <option value="{{ $asset->id }}">{{ $asset->category }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                       <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtDirector">Asset description</label>
                      <select id="ddlGenge" class="form-control" name="description" required="">
                        <option>Choose a Description</option>
                        @foreach($assets as $asset)
                          <option value="{{ $asset->description }}">{{ $asset->description }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtProducer">Location</label>
                      <select id="ddlGenge" class="form-control" name="address" required="">
                        <option>Choose an Address</option>
                        @foreach($assets as $asset)
                          <option value="{{ $asset->address }}">{{ $asset->address }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>  
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtWebsite">Standard price</label>
                      <input id="txtWebsite" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" required="">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtWriter">Date</label>
                      <input id="txtWriter" type="date" class="datepicker form-control" name="occupation_date"
                             required="">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
                <br/>
              </form>
```

and my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validation
    $this->validate($request, array([
        'tenant_id' => 'required',
        'asset_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'occupation_date' => 'required',
    ]));

    //create and save new data
    $tenantProperty = New TenantProperty();
    $tenantProperty->tenant_id = $request->tenant_id;
    $tenantProperty->asset_id = $request->asset_id;
    $tenantProperty->description = $request->description;
    $tenantProperty->address = $request->address;
    $tenantProperty->price = $request->price;
    $tenantProperty->occupation_date = $request->occupation_date;
    $tenantProperty->save();
    //redirect
    return redirect('agent/tenantProperty_list');
}
```

with the route as follows

```
 Route::get('add_tenantProperty', 'TenantPropertyController@create')->name('/add_tenantProperty');
Route::post('add_tenantProperty', 'TenantPropertyController@store');
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$validatedData = $request->validate([..` like on the [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation) page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you just write `$request`, it passes the entire request object but the validate function expect both the arguments to be arrays.

So make a little change and you will be good to go:

```
$this->validate($request, array(  // Removed `[]` from the array.
    'tenant_id' => 'required',
    'asset_id' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'price' => 'required',
    'occupation_date' => 'required',
));
```

Comment: thank you tried it this way but this is what I got  Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in /Applications

Comment: @Omotola, my bad. The problem was the `[]` inside the array. remove them. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, this is another way to solve the validation problem on laravel 5.5 I asked

```
$validation = validator::make($request->all(), [
        'tenant_id' => 'required',
        'asset_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'occupation_date' => 'required',
    ]);
```

For more information visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 0):

```
 $request->validate([ 
'0'=>'',
'tenant_id' => 'required',
'asset_id' => 'required',
'description' => 'required',
'address' => 'required',
'price' => 'required',
'occupation_date' => 'required',]);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable, not only for the OP, but also for the whole community